# Am I supposed to get "GST/HST credit" cheques even if I have substantial savings abroad?

Tags: taxes, canada, hst, gst

I have moved to Canada, Nova Scotia about a year ago, so I filed my first tax return (2017) already. Long story short, I lived the entire year out of my own savings - there  was no income and no taxable expenses. I have been unemployed too.

I have received a handful of cheques from the government since then. The cheques read "GST/NSALT credit" and are not much. I just googled about it, and from [Turbotax](https://turbotax.intuit.ca/tips/what-is-the-gsthst-credit-and-how-do-i-qualify-5500):

> As part of Canada’s progressive tax system, the government introduced
>   the GST/HST tax credit to reimburse some or all of the federal portion
>   of sales taxes to low-income households. The credit is paid quarterly
>   for each tax year, in July, October, January and April, on or around
>   the fifth day of those months. The amount of the credit is based on
>   each family’s net income, plus the number of dependent children. The
>   CRA does not consider the credit taxable income. Application for the
>   GST/HST credit is done automatically through federal tax returns,
>   though it can be claimed only by one spouse or other member of a
>   household.

Which sounds almost definitely what is going on with me (my most recent cheque was on January 5th). Apparently I automatically applied via my tax return and I am eligible for being at least 19. And since I technically have no income, I make for a good candidate.

But that's the thing that bugs me: I have substantial savings abroad (from many years ago - way before 2017), so even if I have no new income over the year it makes me wonder if I really should be getting a cheque at all. Did I make a mistake in my tax return? If it turns out  I shouldn't be getting these cheques, what I am supposed to do?

Comment: Do your assets abroad generate no returns whatsoever?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea no, they don't.

Comment: Presumably, if simply _having_ assets abroad mattered to the CRA in deciding eligibility for GST/HST, there would have been a question on the tax return to that effect (unless you missed it!). If there wasn't, they presumably don't care.